# Docusign log reader

Tags: logging, docusignapi

We need to provide permissions to a third party to read all audit logs of the docusign associated with our company. We want to provide read only access to their apis only. Is this possible and what is the correct way to achieve this?
On a demo account We tried integrated keys(https://admindemo.docusign.com/api-integrator-key), using which we can easily call rest apis to poll for specific timerange audit events. But we can't find a way to limit the access permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign does not have permissions around logs reading, you need to control this on your App. Since user will be coming to your App to read the DS audit events, then you can put control access on your App, and behind the scene you can call /audit_events with proper API credentials.